# How to post List of Object in Post request body Rest webservices

Tags: c#, json, web-services, rest

Unable to form a post request body. Please explain how pass list of items in post request body.

Here is my request body:

```
  "serviceslist":[{"servicecentermapNbr":13,
                     "serviceQty":1},
                    {"servicecentermapNbr":15,
                     "serviceQty":1}]
```

I tried to solve it with lambda expression like below:

```
var services = items.Select(service => new { servicecentermapNbr = service.servicecentermapNbr, serviceQty =service.Quatity}).ToList();
```

But the request body formed like:

```
{System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator<Data_Access.DataModal.ServiceList,<>f__AnonymousType0<int,int>>}
```

Instead of the list of items mentioned above.
Please explain me how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what that `items` object is in your case, but this is how scenario this would usually look:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Create(List<ServiceModel> serviceModelList) {
    //work involving model
}


public class ServiceModel
{
    public int CenterMapNbr { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
}
```